# Excel formula that uses two columns

Tags: excel

Im trying to work a formula in excel Where IF Column B is YR Then column
C=EDATE(TODAY(),-24) but if column B is anything else then column
C=EDATE(TODAY(),-12)

Comment: using an IF statement in Colum C would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula would help:
Type this formula in column c:

```
=IF(B1="YR",EDATE(TODAY(),-24), EDATE(TODAY(),-12))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `IF` formula will suffice:

```
=IF(B1="YR",EDATE(TODAY(),-24),EDATE(TODAY(),-12))
```